# What is the difeerence between parent function and child function in xpath of selenium

Tags: function, selenium, xpath

URL==> http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html
I use the above url for testing purpose

i try to find the web element using parent and child function in xpath,but child and parent function give me an same result,i use the below command

```
parent function==> $x("//div[@class='container-fluid']//parent::div")
child function==> $x("//div[@class='container-fluid']//child::div")
```

Observe that i use the same web element and try to fing it's parent and child element but after running the above cmd i get the similar result
Execute the cmd in cosole tab
How can have same element as a parent as well as child for  particular web element
Please help in above and if not clear the question let me know i try to more describe the question
Thank you in advance

Comment: Classic case of using "//" as magic fairy-dust without understanding what it means. "//" followed by any axis other than child or attribute is pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking it down:

```
//div[@class='container-fluid']//parent::div
```

1. `//` select the root and all of its descendants
2. `div[@class='container-fluid']` from all of the nodes selected in step 1., select all child `div` elements with an attribute `class` equal to `'container-fluid'`
3. `//` select all nodes selected in step 2 and all of their descendants
4. `parent::div` starting from the nodes selected in step 3, select all parents of those nodes that are `div` elements

```
//div[@class='container-fluid']//child::div
```

1. `//` select the root and all of its descendants
2. `div[@class='container-fluid']` from all of the nodes selected in step 1., select all child `div` elements with an attribute `class` equal to `'container-fluid'`
3. `//` select all nodes selected in step 2 and all of their descendants
4. `child::div` starting from the nodes selected in step 3, select all children of those nodes that are `div` elements

So the reason you are getting the same result in both cases is because the `div` you are locating is a parent of one of the nodes selected in step 3 and a child of one of the nodes selected in step 3.

If you are just trying to select the parent or child of the `container-fluid` div, then get rid of the double slashes:

```
//div[@class='container-fluid']/parent::div

//div[@class='container-fluid']/div
```

The `child::` axis is redundant most of the time and can be omitted in this case as I have done above.

Comment: This is all true, adding for OP, you won't find any node `//div[@class='container-fluid']/parent::div` with this since there is actually no parent div for `//div[@class='container-fluid']`